# RegEx/Javascript: How to get the parameter from URL?

Tags: javascript, regex

Hi i have this kind of URLs

```
www.example.com/registration/star/xx223x/xxxx67x/xx
www.example.com/registration/star-mega/x45xx/xxxrfxx/xx
www.example.com/registration/manager/xxx34xx/xx
www.example.com/registration/pro/xxxxx/xxx
```

How can i using javascript and RegEx get the parameter after /registration/ and before the next / into variable? (star, star-mega, manager, pro)

Comment: Have you made any kind of attempt at all? Where are you stuck? Right now this reads a lot like "write this for me."

Comment: Look at `location.pathname` and `Array.split`.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/901115/how-can-i-get-query-string-values-in-javascript?rq=1 ***2282*** votes and you *couldn't* spot that question?

Comment: I stuck with RegEx for this

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky: Note that the OP doesn't have a query string.

Comment: Well it is the different question, and i think it will be useful for a lot of people

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky actually if you have nothing to say, you better move on another question

Comment: @Hanky웃Panky I can wait without the white noise that you do. But i've got the answer. Thank you :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To expand on the awesome answer by Uri Y, here is how you use it in JavaScript:

```
var url = 'www.example.com/registration/star-mega/x45xx/xxxrfxx/xx';
var result = url.match('\/registration\/([^\/]+)');
alert(result[1]);
```

[JSFiddle Here](http://jsfiddle.net/2YEWb/).

Answer (score 2):

How about the following regex: `www\.example\.com\/registration\/([^\/]+)`? see http://regex101.com/r/xS8zZ6

Comment: Thank you! And what is the function that i can use? replace()?